# How do you make V sparse in sklearn.DictionaryLearning?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

`alpha` controls U's sparsity. `transform_alpha` also seems to act on U not V.

I want a sparse code and a sparse dictionary.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.DictionaryLearning.html

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/decomposition.html#dictionarylearning

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is not possible in scikit-learn, simply because other algorithms are necessary.

The framework proposed by Rubinstein et al. [1] seems to fit your use-case: essentially the dictionary is further approximated as `V=PA`, with `P` a base dictionary and `A` a sparse atom-representation matrix. Each column of `A` is constrained to have at most `p` non-zeros and a L2 norm of 1.

[1] Rubinstein, R., Zibulevsky, M. & Elad, M. Double Sparsity: Learning Sparse Dictionaries for Sparse Signal Approximation. IEEE Transactions on Signal Processing 58, 1553–1564 (2010). https://doi.org/10.1109/TSP.2009.2036477